# Stubbing a specific method in a controller with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to stub out a mixin method in my controller tests. The controller includes the `SeatingChartCreator` module, which has already been tested. So all I want to do is stub it out so that it sets the controller `@errors` variable to nil in one test, and to something in another, and then stub it out another time just to make sure that it gets called. I've looked over the RSpec documentation, and it seems like all they provide information on is stubbing a whole class, not just specific methods in the class I am testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stub a method use `allow/receive`. For example:

```
before do
  allow(controller).to receive(:say_hello).and_return('Hello!')
end
```

Comment: How do I verify that the method was called then? Also I tried doing that with a block after receive(...) where I set "@"errors to something, but "@"errors never got set.

Comment: If you want to set an expection instead of stubbing, replace `allow` with `expect`.

Comment: Is there a way to stub it an have it set an instance variable for the controller when it is called?

Comment: No, there isn't. Perhaps you can stub another method that @error is set by?